# Suppress libreoffice headless command outputs which are not via stdout/stderr

Tags: subprocess, stdout, stdin, libreoffice, suppress

Running the following command is outputting to unix terminal, even if stdout/stderr are redirected to a file.

Both commands:

```
libreoffice --headless --convert-to xlsx <my_file> > 1.tmp
libreoffice --headless --convert-to xlsx <my_file> 2> 1.tmp
```

Are printing the following to the terminal (and not to 1.tmp):

```
convert <my_file> using filter : Calc Office Open XML
Overwriting: <out_file>
```

1. How can it be that a process prints to the terminal not via stdin/stderr?
2. How can I suppress those printing? (to be more precise, I'm trying to suppress them through python's subprocess, using stdin=DEVNULL and stdout=DEVNULL - which is unsuccessful).

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Even though your question is surprisingly well and carefully worded for a first question, you might like to take the [tour] and read "[ask]". -- Would you mind to elaborate a bit on the context, please? Which operating system do you use? How did you try the commands? At least the first one works perfectly for me. -- If you also add a [example] of the Python script, it would help us help you.

Comment: Hi, actually I would start by re-asking the theoretical question. How is it possible, in UNIX terminal, that a process will print to the terminal not via stdin/stderr?

Comment: Without knowing exactly, and I have to work on Windows right now: There are devices like `/dev/console` that could be used, may be. -- I will need to try at home, some hours later.